# Make some sample names unique according to conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I've got a dataframe that has this structure:

```
year  name  value 
1999  s1    NA    
2000  s1    0.5   
2001  s1    0.6   
1999  s2    0.5   
2000  s2    0.3
1999  s1    0.4
2000  s1    0.3 
2000  s1    0.3 
2001  s1    0.7
```

As you can see, `s1` is duplicated. I would like to rename the duplicated sample names to something different (e.g. `s1_1` but it doesn't really matter). However, I only want to rename those samples where first non-NA year and last non-NA year are the same.

EDIT: The samples that do not have the same first and last year, I want to remove from the dataframe.

EDIT: Expected output:

```
# Add columns with first and last year
df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(name) %>% dplyr::mutate(first_year = 
dplyr::first(year[!is.na(value)])) 

df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(name) %>% dplyr::mutate(last_year = 
dplyr::last(year[!is.na(value)])) 

# Do something to rename the samples with the same first and last years, and 
# remove duplicated samples with different first and last years 

# Desired output: 

year  name    value first_year last_year
1999  s1      NA    2000       2001
2000  s1      0.5   2000       2001
2001  s1      0.6   2000       2001
1999  s2      0.5   1999       2000
2000  s2      0.3   1999       2000
2000  s1_1    0.3   2000       2001
2001  s1_1    0.7   2000       2001
```

Comment: can you show your expected output?

Comment: Added an edit :)

Comment: I don't understand. 2000 s1 is repeated 3 times. Shouldnt be renamed s1 s1_1 ans s1_2 ? Also, 2001 s1 has the same issue. Can you explain?

Comment: The required condition is still not clear to me. What is the "first" and "last" non-NA year. I can see that 1999 s1 is duplicated but didn't get a "_1". 2000 s1 appears 3 times and only the last one gets a "_1". 2001 s1 appears only twice but already the second one gets a "_1" - so what is the logic?

Comment: The second s1 (1999, 2000) doesn't have the same first and last year, so I don't want it renamed. Just the third s1 (2000, 2001) because it has the same first and last year as the first s1. Sorry if it's unclear!

Comment: Added an edit to show first and last year

Comment: (You don't need to mark edits as such, there is an edit history linked with the centre hyperlink beneath a post.) `[Added] first and last year` If these are derived from the values in the first table: How?

Comment: Hi @greybeard I added an edit to show how I derived first and last years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution.

Given your data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "year  name  value 
1999  s1    NA    
2000  s1    0.5   
2001  s1    0.6   
1999  s2    0.5   
2000  s2    0.3
1999  s1    0.4
2000  s1    0.3 
2000  s1    0.3 
2001  s1    0.7 ", header = TRUE)

df
#>   year name value
#> 1 1999   s1    NA
#> 2 2000   s1   0.5
#> 3 2001   s1   0.6
#> 4 1999   s2   0.5
#> 5 2000   s2   0.3
#> 6 1999   s1   0.4
#> 7 2000   s1   0.3
#> 8 2000   s1   0.3
#> 9 2001   s1   0.7
```

---

Here is a solution in three steps:

1. define id and year interval
2. remove extra names
3. set up suffix

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 

# 1. define id and year interval
df <- df %>% 
 mutate(id = 1 + cumsum(year<=lag(year, default = 0))) %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(first_year = min(year[!is.na(value)]),
        last_year  = max(year[!is.na(value)])) %>% 
 ungroup()
df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#>    year name  value    id first_year last_year
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <int>     <int>
#> 1  1999 s1     NA       1       2000      2001
#> 2  2000 s1      0.5     1       2000      2001
#> 3  2001 s1      0.6     1       2000      2001
#> 4  1999 s2      0.5     2       1999      2000
#> 5  2000 s2      0.3     2       1999      2000
#> 6  1999 s1      0.4     3       1999      2000
#> 7  2000 s1      0.3     3       1999      2000
#> 8  2000 s1      0.3     4       2000      2001
#> 9  2001 s1      0.7     4       2000      2001
 

# 2. remove extra names
df <- df %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
 filter(first_year == first(first_year), last_year == first(last_year)) %>% 
 ungroup()
df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#>    year name  value    id first_year last_year
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <int>     <int>
#> 1  1999 s1     NA       1       2000      2001
#> 2  2000 s1      0.5     1       2000      2001
#> 3  2001 s1      0.6     1       2000      2001
#> 4  1999 s2      0.5     2       1999      2000
#> 5  2000 s2      0.3     2       1999      2000
#> 6  2000 s1      0.3     4       2000      2001
#> 7  2001 s1      0.7     4       2000      2001
 

# 3. set up suffix
df <- df %>% 
 group_by(name, first_year, last_year) %>% 
 mutate(suffix = as.numeric(factor(id))-1) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(suffix = if_else(suffix == 0, "", paste0("_", suffix))) %>% 
 unite(name, name, suffix, sep = "")
 
# final result
df %>% select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>    year name  value first_year last_year
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>      <int>     <int>
#> 1  1999 s1     NA         2000      2001
#> 2  2000 s1      0.5       2000      2001
#> 3  2001 s1      0.6       2000      2001
#> 4  1999 s2      0.5       1999      2000
#> 5  2000 s2      0.3       1999      2000
#> 6  2000 s1_1    0.3       2000      2001
#> 7  2001 s1_1    0.7       2000      2001
```

Comment: Hi, I just realised my upvote hasn't registered as I'm a new user - so I'll just say, thanks so much for your help! I really appreciated it

Comment: what you can do is to accept the answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) out